# Want to insert excel file data into table using ssis - format problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssis

I have created an SSIS package i took 'excel source' taking excel file but my problem is I need to take B7 value from excel file and insert it into database table please help because

B7 values is generated from expression : =MAX($B$32:C284)

[image]

hi I want to take value of `date` i.e `'8/26/2011'` , and value of `NAV` i.e `'93737452.52'`

and want to insert into table i'm using `'excel source '` to take excel file made connection now Select `'Data access mode'` in `'Excel source editor'` as `'SQL command'`

now what command I need to write to get `'date'` and `'NAV'`value as I have pasted picture of excel file please let me know the further steps plese .

Comment: You should make B7 a named range, then it will be available as another table on your data source

Comment: I tried like select B7 from FROM [Sheet1$] but its not working please elaborate with example or any thread :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you only need 2 very specific cell values from the spreadsheet, I would suggest using a **Script Component** to get the values from just those cells instead of using an Excel Source.  Excel Source is really made for getting a bunch of rows & columns that are laid out consistently, not for picking individual cells.

To do this, first drag a **Script Component** from the **Data Flow Transformations** section of toolbox. When the select script component type dialog box appears, check the first option, "Source".

[image]

Next, edit this script component and pick **Inputs & Outputs** from the leftmost column and add the 2 output columns that you will need and set the correct data type for each.

[image]

Then click the Script option, choose your language (I picked Visual Basic 2008 in this case) and then click the **Edit Script** button.

When the IDE comes up, add a reference to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` and add an Imports statement for this at the top of your script. Then in the `CreateNewOutputRows` routine, get a reference to your workbook & worksheet and output the values from the specific cells that you want using the `AddRow()` method. As you can see from the code below, I am getting the values directly from cells b7 & c7 and converting them to the proper type.

[image]

Save your script and exit the IDE and you can now use this script component as your source for your database insert:

[image]

The script will read just the 2 values you want from the cells you specify and provide them to the Data Flow Destination.

While this may look like a lot more work than just dropping an Excel Source in the Data Flow, it gives you much more flexibility and control.

Answer (score 2):

If the file you have can be modified, you can give a name to the cells `B7` and `D7` (You can choose the names "Date" and "NAV", for instance). For that, you need to right-click the cell and then click on "Name a Range". 
[image: Naming a range on excel]

Once you do that, you can pick those names ("Date" and "NAV") as if they were sheets of your excel file. So you can do `select * from FROM [Date$]`, or is going to be available as another sheet if you choose your Data acces mode as "Table or View".

Comment: +1 Much simpler than the solution I proposed. But do you need the $ after "Date"?  Shouldn't the query be `SELECT * FROM [Date]`?

Comment: @PaulStock - I think you are right, and it should be just `select * from [Date]`; but I'm not on a computer with SSIS installed, so I don't really remember the right way to query that range. In any case, op should be aware of this and try your way, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the format of the file is not fixed (i.e. leading blank rows/columns) then I suggest that you make consolidate the column names into one field and remove the blank elements to make it simple for SSIS.

If the file has to maintain the existing format, change the Data Access mode within your Excel source object to SQL Command and then use something similar to the following to exclude empty rows;

```
SELECT        F2, F3
FROM          [Sheet1$]
WHERE        (F2 IS NOT NULL) AND (F2 <> 'USD P&L' and F2 <> 'Date')
```

You will have to use a Data Conversion control to make sense of the resulting data types.

Comment: Thanks !
I have searched and got `OpenRowset()` property of `excel source` for skipping rows :)

Answer (score 1):

Could you force Excel to SaveAs() and choose .csv format ?

I believe this would save values only.