# Import a single Excel cell into SSIS

Tags: excel, ssis

Am trying to import a number of metric values from an Excel file into SSIS. 
I have named each of the cells with data and was hoping to be able to configure a Connection, that would be updated in a ForEach container, to point to each Named Range in turn, in order to bring over the data one value at a time.
I see many articles on how to connect to a Sheet or Table in Excel, but none to a Named Range?  I saw one article on how to bring over one single cell, but that cell was a part of a table.
Can I setup a Connection in SSIS to a single cell, Named or otherwise, and bring back that value?
JK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see you implementing this in one of two ways. The first is just a straight Execute SQL Task that returns a single row. The other being a data flow with, probably a script task as your source.

With each pass through your loop, you'd probably need to modify the Excel connection manager and/or your query string to point to the correct named range

In the section [To create a linked server against an Excel spreadsheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175866.aspx)

> To access data from an Excel spreadsheet, associate a range of cells
>   with a name. A named range can be accessed by using the name of the
>   range as the table name. The following query can be used to access a
>   named range called SalesData using the linked server set up in the
>   previous example.

This [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306572) also describes programmatically access Excel via C#, albeit from ASP.NET but the principal should be the same. My hazy recollection is that the worksheet name would have a $ appended to it, thus sheet1$ while accessing the named range would be without the $.

One thing we ran into with our implementation was our servers did not have the appropriate drivers on them and it required us to install the [Access engine](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255)

Lots of generalities in this answer so if you run into specifics, feel free to ping me.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the top two answers from this question:
[Want to insert excel file data into table using ssis - format problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446785/want-to-insert-excel-file-data-into-table-using-ssis-format-problem/7480251#7480251)
which explains 2 different approaches to doing what you ask.

Comment: We can connect to a single cell in Excel, if that cell is a named range. As mentioned in one of the articles, it needs the right version of MDAC installed and Must be in 32-bit mode. JK

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1930/use-ssis-to-import-one-cell-of-an-excel-file-into-sql-server/#comments.

Unfortunately it didn't help me because i want to set a single variable with the values and use it later on.