# Read Excel cell values with SSIS script task

Tags: c#, excel, ssis, datatable

I am trying to read an Excel file via a **SSIS ScriptTask** to check for certain cell values in that worksheet.

In the code example you can see that the **strSQL** is set to "**H4:H4**" to only read one cell. This cell can only have a true or false value.
Since I also need to check for a certain string value in **B1** I wanted to extend this version.

```
  string filePath = "c:\\test\\testBoolean.XLSX";
  string tabName = "testSheet$";
  string strSQL = "Select * From [" + tabName + "H4:H4]";
  String strCn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
                  + filePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1\";";
  OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(strCn);
  int iCnt = 0;
  OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, cn);
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  objAdapter.Fill(ds, tabName);
  DataTable dt = ds.Tables[tabName];

  foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
  {
      iCnt = iCnt + 1;
      // some processing....
  }
```

What I don't understand is why I get a boolean value with the above **strSQL** statement or with any statment containing the same row number like so:

```
string strSQL = "Select * From [" + tabName + "F4:H4]";
```

Debug-Output:

```
row.ItemArray[2]    false   object {bool}
```

**But** when I set a different range like this one:

```
string strSQL = "Select * From [" + tabName + "F1:H4]";
```

I loose the recognition of the bool value:

```
row.ItemArray[2]   "FALSE"  object {string}
```

I'd much rather like to use the bool value for other processing tasks.

How can I fix this in addition to also reading the B2 value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your connection string specified `IMEX=1`, which tells the driver to treat intermixed data types as text. (See the "Usage Considerations" section of the MSDN article [Excel Connection Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141683.aspx).)

Thus, when you specified a single row

```
string strSQL = "Select * From [" + tabName + "F4:H4]";
```

there was only one possible data type for the third column, and the driver was able to correctly infer it. However, when you specified multiple rows

```
string strSQL = "Select * From [" + tabName + "F1:H4]";
```

and **any** value in the range H1:H4 was not a `bool`, the driver translated **all** values in that column to `string`s.

Assuming that you do in fact have mixed data types in column H and only care about the values in two particular cells, the simplest solution is to query each cell individually. See [Import a single Excel cell into SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646397/import-a-single-excel-cell-into-ssis?rq=1) for some ideas on how to do that.

Comment: this actually makes sense :-) Thanks for the info - I overlooked the IMEX setting.

Answer (score 1):

I would clone most of the code to produce two separate SELECT statements to query the two different cells you are after with separate SQL statements.

Actually I would probably go further and shred the whole script into SSIS components e.g. Execute SQL Tasks or Data Flow Tasks.