# SSIS Import Excel Document Using Column Position, Not Name

Tags: sql, excel, ssis

I was wondering if it was possible to import Excel documents using SSIS by referencing a column by its position?  For example, import columns A,D,M,AA, etc.  I ask because I need to load in several Excel documents from a third party.  Each document contains the same data type in the corresponding columns, except the column names are different for each document.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes but you won't be using the Excel driver and connection manager. Instead, you will use the OLE DB driver and write a SQL Query against the file. For anything but the most basic Excel files, this is my go-to approach for importing data out of Excel.

Various incarnations of my approach

- [Excel Source as Lookup Transformation Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953531/excel-source-as-lookup-transformation-connection/7954984#7954984)
- [script task in SSIS to import excel spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980580/script-task-in-ssis-to-import-excel-spreadsheet/15990184#15990184)
- [Import a single Excel cell into SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646397/import-a-single-excel-cell-into-ssis/7648946#7648946)