# select multiple columns using SQLite3 in Python

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I have a list that contains the name of columns I want to retrieve from a table in the database.
My question is how to make the cursor select columns specified in the list. Do I have to convert nameList to a string variable before include it in the select statement? Thanks

```
nameList = ['A','B','C','D',...]

 with sqlite3.connect(db_fileName) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""
        select * from table
        """)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nameList = ["'A(pct)'",'B','C','D',...]

 with sqlite3.connect(db_fileName) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""
        select {} from table
        """.format(", ".join(nameList)))
```

Comment: what if nameList contains column names like this,  'A(pct)', 'B(pct)'. This will break down your code since Python thought you might be calling some function with parameter pct.  Thanks

Comment: Python doesn't think you are calling a function, it just handles strings as strings. But the SQL might think `A(pct)` is a SQL function..so you might need to put single quotes around those column names. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25210041/4774955

Comment: In SQL, single quotes are for strings, and double quotes are for table/column names.

Comment: @CL Depends on which database software you are using. Single quotes are valid in MSSQL.

Comment: That's why I said "SQL", and did not mention a certain database that does not conform to the SQL standard.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you can be sure your input is sanitized -- to avoid [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack -- you can do:

```
    ...
    qry = "select {} from table;"
    qry.format( ','.join(nameList) )
    cursor.execute(qry)
```

If you're on a really old version of Python do instead:

```
    ...
    qry = "select %s from table;"
    qry % ','.join(nameList) 
    cursor.execute(qry)
```

Comment: Good warning against SQL injection. That still isn't second nature to me coming from an Access background.

Comment: qry = "select {} from table;"
    qry.format( ','.join(nameList) ), it seems Python does not accept since string is immutable and can't be changed? Could you double check? Error message is unrecognized token: "{" .    Thanks

Comment: @bernie: There is still some problem with the updated solution. Nivix's solution seems to be working